# jenkins unmet qualification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I upgraded my installation of jenkins to version 2.249.1.

Previously the approve promotion button was displayed only when the user specified was logged in.  After upgrade the approve promotion is displayed all the time with the title unmet qualification - but its still possible to approve!

I want to remove entirely the option to promote.
[image]

Versions :

Jenkins 2.249.1

git 4.4.4

git client 3.5.1

promoted builds 3.6

Comment: Would be nice if you specified version of Jenkins and (presumably [Promoted Builds](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds) Plugin. Are you a member of or specified "group of people who can run a promotion manually" ? Are you aware of: [SECURITY-746](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-02-26/#SECURITY-746)

Comment: Jenkins 2.249.1 added plugin info as well. All the versions are above what is required in yr link.  "Are you a member of or specified "group of people who can run a promotion manually" thats the whole point of my question - no the logged in user is not, yet they can still promote - even though unmet qualification is displayed (implying the rule has been detected)

Comment: I have not used the plugin or am familiar w/it but thought the info would be useful to define the question context better. I assume it's not a UX issue, where the button is not greyed out and pressing throws up an error "user does not have permission", instead of simply having the button disabled for the user?

Comment: There have been two [recent releases](https://plugins.jenkins.io/promoted-builds/#releases) of the plugin. Have you tried the latest to see if addressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that **handling of approval permissions has [changed](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin/blame/e7889df800a438886af36ed8b49d11a0a094b66d/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/promoted_builds/conditions/ManualCondition.java#L125)** in the plugin with revision 3.0.

Whether the `Approve` button appears or not now depends (only) on whether the current user has the (global, user-specific) permission to promote.

Pre-3.0 versions of the plugin did compare the current user name to the list of users that you specified in the job configuration.

**Bottom line:**

- **You cannot separate approval permission from promotion permission**.
- If you need *project-specific* approval rights for specific users, then you have to establish project-specific promotion permissions (e.g., via the [matrix-auth](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) plugin).

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is a bug already reported on this plugin in 2011 (but version is not mentioned there).

> [JENKINS-11635](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11635): Shouldn't allow manual promotion by 'anonymous'

As per that ticket, this seems to be a long lasting bug unfortunately.

Comment: that is a slightly different bug, in my case the user is logged in and correctly identified. There is even the message "unmet qualification"

Comment: yes, it's true. I was thinking if the user identification is correct; but the enforcement is missing allowing even an anonymous to promote..